# Падение производительности при использовании анимации кнопок

Tags: java, android

Написал простое приложение, в котором имеется 7 кнопок. Сделал простую XML анимацию для каждой кнопки, чтобы при появлении они выезжали. Тестировал приложение на *HTC ONE S* (*Android 4.1.1*) - анимация работала плавно и без нареканий. Стоило открыть приложение на *Highscreen Spider* (*Android 4.3*) -  вся анимация стала очень сильно "глючить": одни подергивания, словно GTA 5 запустил. А ведь этот телефон мощнее, чем *HTC*.

Начал искать проблему. Оказалось, что анимация начинает "глючить", когда на экране отображается более трех кнопок. Если на экране отображается 6 кнопок, и одна появится при помощи анимации, то даже она появится с жуткими подергиваниями.

Можно как-то решить эту проблему? Очень хочется, чтобы приложением было приятно пользоваться. Может, я неправильно код пишу? Или это слишком ресурсоемкая анимация? Или вообще стоит отказаться от анимации?

XML:

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:startOffset="150" >
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0.0%"
        android:duration="500"/>
```

Вызывается вот так, сразу после открытия `Activity`:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
Animation ima = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim1);
image.startAnimation(ima);
```

[image: Скриншот]

Картинки для кнопок формата PNG для HighscreenА используются изображения разрешением 1294x330 Глубина цвета 32, RGB 8bit. Ну а вообще для каждого класса устройства используются свои картинки mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi. Прозрачность 0. Анимаций увеличения нет только перемещения.

Comment: ..Код в студию.

Comment: Покажите сразу layout с 3 кнопками и расскажите про изображения, которые используете для кнопок: размер холста, кол-во цветов, прозрачность и масштабируются ли эти катинки при выводе. В этих местах могут быть проблемы.

Comment: @lsillarionov Добавил

Comment: Начиная с версии 3.0 можно использовать

<application
    largerHeap = "true"> 

Пропиши в манифесте. И твоему приложению будет выделяться больше памяти. Возможно это решит твою проблему. только не забудь выключать анимацию и при переходе на другое окно, очищять картинки.

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажите как выключать анимацию при переходе? @xTIGRx

Comment: @anarbus, У тебя анимация в цикле происходит? или один раз вызывается? Если один раз то не после воспроизведения анимация сама заканчивается. Иначе

animation.cancel();

Comment: Ясно, спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за помощь! Помогло только одно, изменил формат с PNG на JPEG и сделал разрешение по вертикали как у самого устройства, но все равно странно у HTC стандартное разрешение 540x960 и у него была плавная анимация независимо от разрешения кнопок, в то время как у хайскрин 720x1080 и были жуткие лаги...